# Number of products a * b giving a chosen value n in a finite field Fp

Tags: finite-fields, products

Given a finite field $F_p$ for a prime number $p$, and a value $n \in F_p$, I was wondering about the number of pairs $(a,b)$ which product equals $n$.

As an example, in $F_7$, and for $n = 4$, there are (to my knowledge) 4 different (distinct) pairs of integers satisfying the relation :

$$2 \times 2 \\
1 \times 4\\
5 \times 5\\
6 \times 3$$

where the two last solutions are the pairs $(-a,-b)$ of the previous solutions. It is quite easily verifiable for small values of $p$, but what about the general case? Is there a result about the number of such pairs? Or at least some (interesting) bounds?

Comment: wouldn't $n=(a)(na^{-1})$ for all $ a \neq 0$ in the field?

Comment: Sorry if I was not specific. I am asking about distinct pairs (I don't want to count (b,a) if (a,b) already appeared previously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=0$ the pairs are clearly
$$\{ (0,a): a \in \Bbb F_p\}$$
i.e. you have $p$ pairs.

If $n$ is not a square $\pmod p$ (and $n \neq 0$) you have
$$\{ (a,b) : ab=n\} = \{ (a, a^{-1}n): a \in \Bbb F_p^{\times} \}$$
has $p-1$ elements. Since you are considering $(a,b)=(b,a)$, simply divide by $2$ and you get that your pairs are $\frac{p-1}{2}$.

In a similar way you can show that, if $n$ is a (nonzero) square $\pmod p$ you have $\frac{p+1}{2}$ pairs.

Comment: Thanks! do you have any link to an explanation for the square consideration? :)

Comment: You write $n=m^2$ and consider $\{ (a,n^{-1}a) : a \neq \pm m , a \neq 0 \}$. This set has $p-3$ pairs, made of distinct elements (i.e. $(a,b)$ with $a \neq b$). Divide by 2, and then add the two pairs $(m,m)$ and $(-m,-m)$. The total is $$\frac{p-3}{2}+2= \frac{p+1}{2}$$