# Number of solutions to $x^2−y^2=a$ over a finite field.

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Consider F is a finite field with $ q$ elements, where $q=p^n$, p prime, and n is an integer. Give the number of solutions of pairs (x,y) for the equation $$ x^2-y^2=a $$ according to the value of $ q $ and $ a $ in F.

I have resolved the case where $p=2$ and $p≠2$ with $a=0$. However, I encountered an issue in the case where $p≠2$ and $a≠0$. My initial idea was to find all possible differences between square numbers and then look for cases with equal differences. However, I quickly realized that I couldn't solve the problem $ a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2 $ in a finite field.

Later, I changed my strategy and found that all solutions satisfy the form
$$ \left(\frac{b^{-1}+ab}{2},\frac{b^{-1}-ab}{2}\right) $$
However, I am unable to determine the total number of solutions of this form.

Please provide me with some ideas or help me solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: So the question is, how many different pairs $\left( \frac{b^{-1}+ab}{2} , \frac{b^{-1}-ab}{2} \right ) $ are there?

Comment: Isn't it just $q-1$? Every value of $b\neq0$ gives a different solution.

Comment: If two solutions are the same, $s=(\tfrac12(1/b+ab),\tfrac12(1/b-ab))=s'=(\tfrac12(1/b'+ab'),\tfrac12(1/b'-ab'))$, then in particular $s_1+s_2=s_1'+s_2'$, that is, $1/b=1/b'$, so $b=b'$. The representation of $s$ by $b$ is unique.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483470/number-of-products-a-b-giving-a-chosen-value-n-in-a-finite-field-fp, considering $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the equation

$$xy=a \tag1$$

over $\Bbb F_q$ and with $a\neq0$. This equation has obviously $q-1$ different solutions: For any $x\neq0$, the pair $(x,a/x)$ is a solution. And $x=0$ is not a solution.

Then consider the mapping
$$\begin{align}
\Bbb F_q^2 &\quad\to\quad \Bbb F_q^2 \\
(x,y) &\quad\mapsto\quad (x-y, x+y)
\end{align}\tag2$$
which is a bijection if $2\nmid q$ because its discriminant is a unit in $\Bbb F_q$.

Because $(2)$ is a bijection, it does not change the number of solutions when we apply it to $(1)$, and the result of the transformation applied to $(1)$ is:

$$(x-y)(x+y) = x^2-y^2 = a \tag3$$

Hence $(3)$ has also $q-1$ solutions provided $a\neq0$ and $2\nmid q$.

If $a=0$, then $(1)$ has obviously $2q-1$ solutions, namely $\{(x,0)\}\cup\{(0,x)\}$: The cardinality of the union is the sum of the cardinalities of the two sets, which is $2q$ but subtracted by the cardinality of the intersection, which is $\#\{(0,0)\}=1$.

#### Characteristic 2

Remaining is the case where $q=2^n$. Now [every element $a\in\Bbb F_{2^n}$ is a square](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4069143/746312) so you can write $a=r^2$ and hence $(3)$ can be written as:

$$
x^2=a+y^2 = r^2+y^2 = (r+y)^2 \tag 4
$$
Also because every element is a square (and as $\Bbb F_q$ is finite), $x\mapsto x^2$ is injective, and therefore taking square roots on both sides of $(4)$ yields:
$$
x=r+y\tag 5
$$
which has $q$ different solutions for each $r$, and thus also $q$ different solutions for each $a$ (again because squaring is injective).

#### Conclusion

$$
\text{Number of solutions} =
\begin{cases}
q-1, &\text{ if } 2\nmid q \text{ and } a\neq0\\
2q-1, &\text{ if } 2\nmid q \text{ and } a=0\\
q, &\text{ if } 2\mid q\\
\end {cases}$$

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I know no theory of finite fields, but taking the question from what you achieved, we have to count the size of the set $$S=\left\{\left(\frac{b^{-1}+ab}{2},\frac{b^{-1}-ab}{2}\right):b\in F^*\right\}.$$

1. Breaking the problem in smaller parts, I'd count the left $L=\left\{\frac 1 2(b^{-1}+ab):b\in F^*\right\}$ and right $R=\left\{\frac 1 2(b^{-1}-ab):b\in F^*\right\}$ pieces separately.
2. Now to count the size of $L$, I'd note that purely syntactically it's defined as the image of a function $f_L:F^*\to F^*$ $$f_L(b)=\frac 1 2(b^{-1}+ab).$$
   If the function were an injection, we'd know the answer because $L=f_L(F^*)$ would be the whole $F^*$ (because it's finite), so next I'd try to "measure the non-injectivity" of $f_L$.
3. To this goal, take $f_L(b)=f_L(b')$ and see that (if I computed right) $b'$ is either $b$ or $1/ab$, and conversely.$$\forall b,b'\in F^*:f_L(b)=f_L(b')\Leftrightarrow (b=b' \textrm{ or } bb'=1/a)$$
   That is, for each $b\in F^*$, $f_L$ produces either a unique result, or is the same as $f_L(1/ab)$. The former happens only if $b=1/ab$, that is, if $b^2=1/a$.
4. Therefore, the total number of different outputs of $f_L$ is **the number of square roots of $1/a$ plus half of the rest of $F^*$**: $$|L|=|f_L(F^*)| = \left|\sqrt{\{1/a\}}\right| + \frac 1 2\left|F^*\setminus\sqrt{\{1/a\}}\right|$$ where I lazily denoted $\sqrt{\{1/a\}}=\{b\in F^*:b^2=1/a\}$.
   Similarly, $|R|= \left|\sqrt{\{-1/a\}}\right| + \frac 1 2\left|F^*\setminus\sqrt{\{-1/a\}}\right|$.

If what I read here (http://cap-lore.com/MathPhys/Field/finite/sqrt.html) is true, then $|\sqrt{\pm\{1/a\}}|$ is either 0 or 2, but I don't know why. You can substitute in the formulas to get a further evaluated answer. Anyway, we're back in finite fields theory land so I hope you can take it from here :)

Comment: I understand what you want to say. Your process is essentially correct, except in case 3 where you need to cosider b≠0 (0 means multiplicative identity element in a field). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I work only with $b\in F^*$ - I defined $f_L$ only on $F^*=F\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: I wanted to show that the problem is easily solvable starting from what you got, using purely elementary means - in comparison with emacs's answer which is a solution on its own.